# WCF - Access Denied when creating folder

Tags: wcf, iis, file-permissions

I've built a WCF service and want to host it on IIS. One of the features I want is to programmatically create a subfolder in the WCF webhost root, to persist some json files.
I've tested it on my local dev IIS Express and it works fine, which is no surprise 'cause I have all the necessary permissions.
Now, I want to publish it on my public domain. For this, I've created a subdomain on Plesk and a subfolder within httpdocs. I've copied the web.config file and the Bin folder from my dev machine to this folder on my domain. But, when I enter the svc url on my browser I get a access denied exception (the folder is created in a dependency injected in my service, that's why I get the exception at this point).

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Access to the path
>   'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\««my domain»»\httpdocs\VersioningService\Repository' is
>   denied.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
>   path
>   'C:\Inetpub\vhosts\««my domain»»\httpdocs\VersioningService\Repository' is
>   denied.

Below is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add factory="VersioningService.Services.ManualMajorMinorVersioningHostFactory"
             relativeAddress="~/ManualMajorMinorVersioning.svc"
             service="VersioningService.Services.ManualMajorMinorVersioning" />
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

This is what I use to get the current assembly path:

```
var assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
```

Note: If I use the ProgramData folder I get NO exception, but I would prefer to have a subfolder within the WCF folder.

This is clearly a permissions issue. Do I need to add something else to my web.config?
Do I need to ask my host provider to give some extra permissions to some user?

Comment: It's not about config, you just need to give proper access to your application pool user on this folder: C:\Inetpub\vhosts\««my domain»»\httpdocs\VersioningService\Repository

Comment: You _really_ don't want to store stuff in `c:\inetpub\...`. One slip and IIS will end up executing files with malicious code.

Comment: @Uriil: In order to ask my provider for permissions to VersioningService folder (and its subfolder) I need to know the user who's running the WCF service. Can you tell what user is supposed to be?

Comment: I would guess: 'IIS AppPool\VersioningService', but you are using Plesk. it's hard to say. Best thing is to ask you provider to configure permissions

Comment: @Uriil: I'm already on it. Thanks a lot, mate